# QDir::exists returns true for invalid directory

Tags: qt, qt4

I am having problem with checking the existence of the directory.
i take path from user input (e.g QLineEdit) and check for directory exists or not and if user specify the path "K:\" (k drive does not exists at all) my code becomes like this

```
QDir tmp("K:\\");
if(tmp.exists())
   return true;
else
  return false;
```

Ideally it should return false, as the Driver Letter "K" is not mapped, but unfortunately it returns true all the time, does anyone have any idea why is it like that? or
what is the correct method to check the existence of the directory?

Comment: QDir docs state that you should use / instead of \\. Try the static function drives(), which provides a list of root directories for each device that contains a filing system, and see if it lists k:.

Comment: thanks, let me try with this...

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1. Try tmp.makeAbsolute()
2. If that doesn't work, try substituting QDir tmp ("K:/"); (Unix forward slash instead of DOs/Windows backslash).

Comment: makeAbsolute(), returns true as well... ;-(

Answer (score 0):

More beautiful way to check for drives is [QDir::drives()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdir.html#drives) method. Also you need to use [platform independent directory seperator](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdir.html#separator) for [QDir::exists()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdir.html#exists).